# Why Spring Data MongoDB does not provide the "hint" option for Aggregate operations, mongodb Driver does, but I don't know how to use it

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I often use MongoTemplate for aggregate operations, but it is not efficient. I want to "hint" to specify my own index to improve performance

However, the "hint" option cannot be added in AggregationOptions

I saw that DBCollection might be able to do this but I didn't find a way to do this. AggregateOperation is not a parameter in DBCollection's aggregate method and AggregateOperation is the only place I can find that can use "hint"

```
mongodb version is4.0.4
Spring-data-mongodb version is 2.1.4
The mongodb-driver version is 3.8.2
JDK 11
```

1.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOption vailable parameters:

```
public AggregationOptions(boolean allowDiskUse, boolean explain, @Nullable Document cursor,
            @Nullable Collation collation) {

        this.allowDiskUse = allowDiskUse;
        this.explain = explain;
        this.cursor = Optional.ofNullable(cursor);
        this.collation = Optional.ofNullable(collation);
    }
```

2.com.mongodb.AggregationOptions Available parameters:

```
AggregationOptions(AggregationOptions.Builder builder) {
        this.batchSize = builder.batchSize;
        this.allowDiskUse = builder.allowDiskUse;
        this.outputMode = builder.outputMode;
        this.maxTimeMS = builder.maxTimeMS;
        this.bypassDocumentValidation = builder.bypassDocumentValidation;
        this.collation = builder.collation;
    }
```

I just want to improve the efficiency of the query through the index. The speed of the query is too slow. A complex query requires 20s. The simple query also needs 4~5s.

English is not very good, please forgive me if you don’t express it clearly.

Comment: the same issue in 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint in AggregationOption was implemented recently [SpringDataMongoDB Release 3.1], you can use it like

```
    Aggregation
      .newAggregation(aggrgationOperations)
      .withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().hint(new Document("fieldName", 1)).build()
```

or for a geoSpatial query, just change the index to the location field like:

```
AggregationOptions.builder().hint(new Document("fieldName", "2dsphere").build();
```

Comment: There are two kinds of hints in MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate): s String with the name of the index or a document, which describes the index. Spring only supports the document form, which is more fragile compared to the index name. Anyone an idea on how to use the index name in Spring?